# Wordpress Nav - Horizontal Nav with dropdown

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a horizontal nav with a drop down in wordpress.

This is the code I'm tryin to make using the wordpress nav:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I have for the PHP is this:

```
<?php $defaults = array( 

 'container_class' => 'dropdown', 
 'container_id'    => '',
 'container'       => '',
 'menu_class'      => 'dropbtn', 
 'menu_id'         => '',
 'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',

); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

What it puts out is this:

```html
<ul class="dropbtn" id="menu-desktop-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-311" id="menu-item-311"><a href="link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-266" id="menu-item-266"><a href="link">Name</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276" id="menu-item-276"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274" id="menu-item-274"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275" id="menu-item-275"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-271" id="menu-item-271"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-270" id="menu-item-270"><a href="link">Name</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277" id="menu-item-277"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-272" id="menu-item-272"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

It's not getting me what I want. I've tried several other things, but I'm really confused on what I need to change to make this work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

here is simple dropdown menu on hover

```css
.dropbtn > li {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 20px;
float: left;
}

.dropbtn .sub-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
display: none;
width: 150px;
margin-left: -75px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.dropbtn .sub-menu li {
display: block;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #d0d0d0;
}

.dropbtn > li:hover .sub-menu {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropbtn" id="menu-desktop-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-311" id="menu-item-311"><a href="link">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-266" id="menu-item-266"><a href="link">Name</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-276" id="menu-item-276"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-274" id="menu-item-274"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-275" id="menu-item-275"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-271" id="menu-item-271"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-270" id="menu-item-270"><a href="link">Name</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-277" id="menu-item-277"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
 <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-272" id="menu-item-272"><a href="link">Name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly where I want to be. But the code does help get me closer. I now have a couple other issues. But I think I can fix those. Thank you so much!